# How to use Angular 4 + BootStrap Badge with Multiple Line?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

How to use Angular 4 + BootStrap Badge with Multiple Line?

My HTML:

```
<span [hidden]="docker.code==0" class="badge badge-danger">{{docker.console}}</span>
```

I try with:

`line1\nline2`  or `line1<br/>nline2`

I try again with:

```
<span [hidden]="docker.code==0" class="badge badge-danger" ng-bind-html-unsafe="docker.console"></span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a solution:

```
<span [hidden]="docker.code==0" class="badge badge-danger"><div [innerHTML]="docker.console"></div></span>
```